# How to tune /etc/fstab for HDD read performance in ubuntu servers?

Tags: server, hard-drive, fstab

If I want to get the most of my HDDs what are the best fstab settings?

This is a server, with very low risk of losing power, and I have a full backup of everything, so increasing performance at any cost is acceptable.

The disks will be mostly used for reading, almost no writing.

I couldn't find anything useful on google, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is an **XY problem**. There is no solution in changing `/etc/fstab`. The purpose of this file is simply to define where partitions are, what their names are (`UUID`) and what pseudonyms they are given such as `/`, `/boot`, `/home`, `/data`, `/mnt/windows10`, etc.

If you want to speed up HDD access the best method is with lots of RAM and populating it with data from disk. For example assume you have a file `/data/popluar_file.db` which is 4 GB and you want to put it into RAM. Use:

```
cat /data/popular_file.db > /dev/null
```

RAM should be reduced by 4 GB but file access into it will be 100 times faster.